# .setOnClickListener(this); Causing app crash

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

Currently working on a tic tac toe game for android. I am using a GameView and I am running into the issue of every time I run my app it crashes due to .setOnClickListener(this); If anyone has any helpful tips, that would be great.
P.s. The button A1 has been placed on the layout.

```
public class GameView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Paint bluePaint, redPaint;
    private Bitmap a1Tile, a2Tile, a3Tile, b1Tile, b2Tile, b3Tile, c1Tile, c2Tile, c3Tile;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    int playerTurnCount = 0;
    private Button A1;
    Button[] btnGridArray;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bluePaint = new Paint();
        redPaint = new Paint();
        bluePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        a1Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a1tile);
        a2Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a2tile);
        a3Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a3tile);

        b1Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b1tile);
        b2Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b2tile);
        b3Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.b3tile);

        c1Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c1tile);
        c2Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c2tile);
        c3Tile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.c3tile);

        A1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.a1Btn);

        btnGridArray = new Button[]{A1};

        for(Button btn : btnGridArray){
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawRect(100,100,100, 80, bluePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(a1Tile, 60, 80, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(a2Tile, 280, 80, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(a3Tile, 500, 80, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b1Tile, 60, 280, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b2Tile, 280, 280, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b3Tile, 500, 280, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(c1Tile, 60, 480, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(c2Tile, 280, 480, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(c3Tile, 500, 480, null);
        redPaint.setTextSize(72);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Button btn = (Button) v;
        btnClicked(btn);
    }

    public void btnClicked(Button btn){
        if(playerTurn){
            btn.setText("X");
            btn.setTextSize(25);
        }else{
            btn.setText("O");
            btn.setTextSize(25);
        }
        playerTurn = !playerTurn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the view lifecycle (https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN). My guess is that your view isn't in a state that it can be used as a listener yet.

Comment: You are getting NullPointerException, right? That's because you are trying to call findViewById to search for a View which is not inflated into your View (GameView). From where does a1Btn come from?

Comment: @scana this is extending a `View` not an `Activity`

Comment: Post your layout please. I think you're not setting the `onClick` function in your layout

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am aware of that, it should actually extend a ViewGroup to work like he/she wants it to work.

Comment: @scana a1btn is a button I placed on the layout.

Comment: Yes, I can read that clearly in the question. Unfortunately, I don't know what your layout is, could you please post it?

Comment: @scana Not entirely sure if you are asking for my full xml file or just the layout itself. I included both.

Comment: @scana Layout: https://gyazo.com/d97fc36dc8358ba548d1a7dc8ebac721                   XML: https://gyazo.com/f33f8d44fc20711308faf451d09af981 https://gyazo.com/2e77f90c77e68c4a89cc09335e998b23 https://gyazo.com/59135f4ff669d15219d379d902f56180

Comment: Ok. Basically, what you need to do is to inflate that layout into your GameView (if you wanna access that specific button from inside of your GameView). Read more about implementing custom views by extending ViewGroups (it could be a FrameLayout for your case) and inflate that XML file into your GameView.